# Running a long code using facebook API

Tags: php, python, facebook, api

I'm trying to make an app that goes and does actions for all the friends that the user of the app has. The problem is I didn't find yet a platform which I can develop such app as that on.
At first I tried using PHP, I used heroku and my code worked but because I had many friends the loop went more than 30 seconds and the request timed out and the operation stopped in the middle of the action.
I don't mind using any platform I just want it to work!
Python, C++, PHP. They all are fine for me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with that you can change the timeout settings, depending on where the restriction is set, can be on the php as explained [set_time_limit function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

> Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is
> reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30
> seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the
> php.ini.

but it can also be set on the server itself.
Another issue is that routers on the route also have their own timeout limit, so from my experience ~60 seconds is the max.

As for what you want to do, the problem is not which language/technology you use, but the fact that you're making a lot of http requests to facebook which take a bit of time, and I believe that this is your bottleneck, and if that's the case then there's not much you can improve by choosing something other than php (though you can go with [NIO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O) which should improve the IO performance).

With that said, php is not always the best solution, depends on the task at hand.
Java or any other compiled language should perform better than a scripted language (php, python), and if you go with C++ you will top 'em all, but will you feel comfortable to program your app in C++?

Choose the language/technology you feel most "at home" with, if you have a selection to choose from then figure out what you need from your app and then research on which will perform better for what you need.

---

## Edit

Last time I checked the maximum number of friends was limited to 5000.
If you need to to run a graph request per user friend then there's simply no way that you can do that without keeping the user waiting for way too long, regardless of timeouts.

You have two options as I see it:

1. Make the client asynchronous, you can use web sockets, comet, or even issue an ajax request every x seconds to get the computed data.
   That way you don't need to worry about timeouts and the user can start getting content quickly.
2. Use the javascript api to make the graph requests, that way you completely avoid timing out, plus you reduce a huge amount of networking from your servers.
   This option might not be available for you if you need your servers for the computation, if for example you depend on data from your db.

As for the "no facebook SDK for C++" issue, though I don't think it's even relevant, it's not a problem.
All facebook SDKs are simply wrappers for https request, so implementing your own SDK is not that hard, though I hate thinking about doing it with C++, but then again I hate thinking about doing anything with C++.

Comment: The problem is I can't use facebook SDK with C++ sadly.
Also, The site hosting the code limits max_execution_time to 30 seconds.. :(

Comment: Edited my answer, it was too long for a comment

Comment: Firstly, Thanks for your help.
The problem isn't loading friends but writing on each friends wall something.
How can I make the client asynchronous? Do you have any example? I'm pretty new to networking and PHP and all I manage to accomplish is by my knowledge in other languages.